# How to use pubsub notifications for cloud storage to trigger dataflow pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to integrate a Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline with [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications).
The idea is start processing a file as soon it is created.
The messages are being published and with `PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()` source I manage to extract the file URI:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<String> uris = p.apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
            .withTimestampAttribute(PUBSUB_TIMESTAMP_LABEL_KEY)
            .fromSubscription(options.getPubsubSubscription()))
            .apply(MapElements
                    .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                    .via((PubsubMessage msg) -> {
                        String bucket = msg.getAttribute("bucketId");
                        String object = msg.getAttribute("objectId");
                        GcsPath uri = GcsPath.fromComponents(bucket, object);
                        return uri.toString();
                    }));
```

Which `PTransform` can be used to start reading/processing each file in the `uris PCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Beam at HEAD includes a PTransform that does exactly what you want: [TextIO.readAll()](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L61) reads a `PCollection<String>` of filepatterns or filenames. It will be available in Beam 2.2.0, but for now you can just build a snapshot of Beam yourself from the github repo and depend on that.

Comment: readAll() seems to do the trick. Do you know whether snapshots are build/published in any public maven repo ?

Comment: You could try [Nexus Repository Manager](https://repository.apache.org/#nexus-search;gav~org.apache.beam~beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform~~~~kw,versionexpand) or include 
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>`
in your POM.

Answer (score 0):

Combing Cloud Storage change notifications with [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) should be a good option (still in beta though).

Using Cloud Functions you can launch a Dataflow job using some Javascript code. This is a very good [blogpost](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) that should get you on the way. You Dataflow job will kick-off whenever a new file lands in a bucket or a file changes and will process these files.

If you want to stick to your approach, you might want to use the [Google Cloud Storage Java SDK](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to read the files in a custom [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-pardo). Not sure if that approach is preferable though.

Comment: We'll have files arriving every minute, how can we pipe an unbounded source (PubSub) to a bounded one (Text). Cant use neither `TextIO` nor `FileBasedSource` based solution for per line processing?

Comment: @FábioUechi
There is 2 architectures I can think of:
1) Using Cloud Functions as stated above to notify of a new file arriving and then processing the files by publishing them line per line to a Pub/Sub topic. A streaming Dataflow job subscribes to this PubSub topic and does the rest of the processing.
2) As mentioned above, your Dataflow job reads from the PubSub topics with the URLs and ou use the Cloud Storage SDK in a custom DoFn to read the files and process them.

There might be other options, I'd be more than happy to hear about.

Comment: I ended up implementing 2). But I think @jkff TextIO.realAll() suggestion would be better since it seems to handle large files splitting.

Comment: @FábioUechi Makes sense! I just was not aware yet of the new PTransform.